# How to parse JSON to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, http

I have a JSON string from a http request I need to store in a MySql table, columns and rows

I need to do it in Node.js. It's not a problem to get the JSON string via the http request. http://lonobox.com/api/index.php?id=100004854

The problem is to convert it to columns and rows and store it in MySql. Alternative postgre

This is my JSON string

```
[
    {
        "200004854": {
            "temperature": "14.2",
            "humidity":"68"
        }
    },
    {
        "200005584": {
            "temperature": "20",
            "humidity":"51"
        }
    },
    {
        "100004854": {
            "barometer":"1002"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing the json data using JSON.parse().
The resultant will be an array of data.
If you are open to trying other dbs then I suggest using mongodb.
In that you can directly push the data as a json.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it by using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) npm modules

After defining your 'app' using express and my-sql connection you can use a code similar to this example:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {                        //handles request when URL is accessed
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/myfile.html'));
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {                       //handles request when data is sent

var jsondata = req.body;
var values = [];

for(var i=0; i< jsondata.length; i++)
  values.push([jsondata[i].name,jsondata[i].age]);

connection.query('INSERT INTO members (name, age) VALUES ?', [values], function(err,result) {
  if(err) {
     res.send('Error encountered');
  }
 else {
     res.send('Data sent successfully');
  }
 });
});
```

This the method that I was able to find when I had to do something similar, this might or might not be the best way to approach this